# What is "A non-PC American woman overseas?"

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, crossword-clues

I'm stuck on the last clue of a cryptic crossword. The clue is:

> A non-PC American woman overseas? (6)

The cross letters are A_R_A_, confirmed by "check answers."

<sub>Cryptic Crosswords iPhone app, Pack 1, Puzzle 16, Clue 16</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I was typing this up, I figured it out:

> ABROAD
>  [A] [non-PC American woman = broad] [overseas = abroad]
>
>  I'm not quite sure if "American" is there for a particular reason besides just being filler. Is "broad" really restricted to American women?

Comment: "Broad" isn't a word for an American woman but it's an American word for a woman.

Comment: That would explain it. Do Brits really not use it?

Comment: It would be widely understood but rarely used I'd say. My dictionary (Chambers) specifically marks it as American

Comment: you should accept your own answer. :)